# Replace all instances of a character inside a specific HTML element/tag

Tags: html, regex, macos, dreamweaver, replace

Adobe Dreamweaver's Search & Replace feature offers to limit its scope to "only inside of the xxxx HTML tag".

I want to do this with Mac OS X' command line (so will do anything that comes bundled with it).

For example, how do I remove all instances of the character "a" inside all `<h1>` with the command line?

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to change from/to?

Comment: For instance, delete all instances of hyphens inside <h1>lot-s of hy-pen-s to e-lim-i-nate</h1> but not inside any other tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unix's sed command (which is available on mac too).
e.g.

```
$ cat foo.xml 
<h1>axyzabca</h1>
<a href="foo.com">abc</a>
<h1>aa</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1></h1>

$ cat foo.xml | sed 's/<h1>a*\([^a]*\)a*\([^a]*\)a*<\/h1>/<h1>\1\2<\/h1>/g' 
<h1>xyzbc</h1>
<a href="foo.com">abc</a>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
```

(foo.xml is a sample input which covers common test cases)

Comment: I must add that unless you are doing this while editing code, processing xml/html with regular expressions is generally a bad idea. Please see [codinghorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) to understand why.

Comment: Wouldn't this just remove that exact pattern of some a's at the begining, some together in the middle, and some at the end (that is, exactly 3 sets, no less no more, of a's)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The example xml and sample run I gave shows different cases. Anyways, the point was to show you how you can do it using sed. You can tweak the regular expression to your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of a one-liner, but --

```
perl -ni -e '
    $/ = undef; $x = <>; $y = "";
    while ($x =~ m#^(.*?<h1>)(.*?)(</h1>)(.*)$#si) {
      $x = $4; $y .= $1; $c = $3;
      ($b = $2) =~ s/a/(something else)/g;
      $y .= $b . $c;
    } print $y . $x;
' filename.html
```